# Segment error when using boost::asio::serial_port in ROS

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to use the boost::asio::serial_port class to read messages from a serial port. I tried to use it as a member of a class, like this:

```
class AnchorTalker
{
    private:
    boost::asio::serial_port sp;
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    void TrySerialOpen(const char * portname);
    public:
    AnchorTalker() : sp(ios) {};
};
```

And then I tried to write a simple node to test if I am able to open the port, like this:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    ros::init(argc,argv,"anchor_talker");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    AnchorTalker talker;
    ROS_INFO("success");
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

It managed to pass catkin_make, but when I use rosrun, it throws segmentation fault. If I put the ROS_INFO ahead of the AnchorTalker line, the program will stuck just after printing the word success. I wonder what is causing the problem?
I tried to rebuild the files in visual studio, and it says something's wrong about ntdll.dll

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Luckily, I just found an example using serial_port, and finally solved the problem by checking each line. Seems I need to put ios ahead of sp so that ios gets constructed first. Didn't really know that the order makes differences.